Why did Robb start his line of questioning with a reference to microfilm?
Near the end of Oppenheimer, the following exchange takes place:

ROBB
During your interview with Boris Pash in 1943, did you refer to microfilm?
OPPENHEIMER
No.
ROBB
You never said 'a man at the consulate expert in the use of microfilm'?
OPPENHEIMER
Not specifically.

I get the point of this line of questioning. It's supposed to ambush and slander Oppenheimer with a recorded conversation he didn't know was recorded and potentially catch him perjuring himself. But why lead the questioning about microfilm, specifically? That seems like the least interesting piece of the interview and seems to just tip Robb's hand that he chose a purposefully obscure detail to trip Oppenheimer up when he shouldn't have needed to use such an amateur trick.

Microfilm was used by various intelligence agencies to photograph classified documents and smuggle them out of secure facilities (such as Los Alamos). “A man at the [Soviet] consulate expert in the use of microfilm” would have certainly been an NKVD/KGB or GRU case officer. So, the line of questioning is whether Oppenheimer was in touch with Soviet intelligence, or at least aware of such a person, without having reported it.
